# Benefits of Future.of() versus Timer.run() in dart?

Tags: timer, dart, future

Dart has many ways of creating, processing and returning async functions. One of the most common methods is to:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

var completer = new Completer();

// Previously this would have been new Timer(0, () => ....);
Timer.run(() => completer.complete(doSomethingHere()));
return completer.future;
```

However dart also provides a constructor for Future's directly such as:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

return new Future.of(() => doSomethingHere());
```

I am aware that the `Timer.run()` version may be cancelled using the return value of the static method. And that the `new Future.of()` version is slightly less code, is there a particular benefit to using `new Future.of()` over `Timer.run()` (or vice versa). Or are the benefits simply those that I just mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Future.of` returns a Future, `Timer.run` does not return anything. To me, this is the main difference.

I use `Future.of` if I want to return a value as a Future.

I use `Timer.run` if I want to run some function later, and I don't care about the value that it produces.

One big difference is *when* the function is run, though.

For `Future.of`, the function is run in the current event loop, and only its *value* is made available in the next event loop.

For `Timer.run`, the function is run in the next event loop.

Comment: Thanks Seth. That is a big difference (when the callback is run). I was not aware that the Future.of runs the callback in the current loop and only saves the result for the next loop. (Though the Timer.run static method cannot be passed a delay, a new Timer object is passed the duration.).

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that they are two different things. `Timer` can be used anywhere for so many purposes. It could be used on the client-side for waiting for layout to happen before running more code, for example. So, it may not have anything to do with futures. I use the timer sometimes in client-side code to wait for a layout.

Timer is a generic class for delaying the running of some code. No matter whether it has anything to do with futures or not. Another example could be client-side animations. Nothing to do with futures or dealing with data asynchronously.

Futures, however, are monads that help you to program asynchronous programs. Basically a replacement to passing plain callback functions.

Use `new Future.of()` when writing asynchronous programs and it suits your situation (the same goes with `new Future.immediate()`.

Use the `Timer` class if you want to delay the running of some code.

If what you want to do is to use futures for asynchronous programming and at the same time delay the code, forget the timer class unless you need some real delay (more than 0/next event).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it doesn't exactly answer my question. I'm familiar with what the Future and Timer classes are. I was specifically asking about the underpinnings of Timer.run static method (which is specifically designed to 'Run asynchronously as soon as possible.') Versus new Future.of() which provides a future for the supplied callback which will run in the next event loop. I mentioned the benefits I saw (Timer.run allows it to be cancelled before the next event loop and Future.of doesn't require an explicit completer). I wanted to know if that's the only difference.

Comment: If you want to return a future, and complete it as soon as possible, but not in the current event loop, then just use `new Future.of()` rather than the timer class. Sure, you could also do the more complex way you showed us by calling `complete()` in the timer's callback, but it doesn't really give you anything meaningful. You might have seen some code using the timer class, because in the earlier SDK it wasn't possible to complete a future "ASAP in the next event loop". Now it is.